# Memory utilization of an ls *<regexp>* | <command>

Tags: memory

I inherited a simple bash script which does:
set a variable to a bunch of directories:

```
DIR="dir1 dir2 dir3 ... dirx"
```

It then does a:

```
for i in `echo $DIR`
do
   for j in `ls $i/*<regexp>*`
   do
      (<command to $j>)
   done
done
```

What I now see is that though the files itself aren't larger than 50GB, I do see the  part of the script taking up > 200 GB of memory, according to a ps output.

Is the shell globbing the files all together?  What is the more efficient way to be doing this?

Comment: (Nitpick: that's a shell pattern, not a regex.) Yes, the shell does make a list if all the filenanes before the loop. But the number looks quite large, it's only filenames after all.

Comment: That is a... pretty bad script. Can you explain what you want the script to do so we can give you a safer version? That one is like a small showcase of bad shell script practices: i) it is [parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), ii) it doesn't quote its variables, iii) it uses CAPS for variable names, iv) it's using the deprecated `\`command\`` instead of `$(command)`.

Answer (score 0):

200GB of memory seems rather excessive, and unexplainable by the commands shown above. However you can make the loop more efficient and less error-prone, by avoiding the command substitutions:

```sh
for i in $DIR
do
   for j in "$i"/*<pattern>*
   do
      (<command to $j>)
   done
done
```